# spans are coming vertical

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve pagination in my page .

```
<span height="40px"><span class="pg-normal" onclick="pager.prev();"> « Prev </span>
 |
<span id="pg1" class="pg-selected" onclick="pager.showPage(1);" style="display: block;">1</span>
<span id="sp1" style="display: block;">|</span>
<span id="pg2" class="pg-normal" onclick="pager.showPage(2);" style="display: block;">2</span>
<span id="sp2" style="display: block;">|</span>
<span id="pg3" class="pg-normal" onclick="pager.showPage(3);" style="display: block;">3</span>
    <span id="sp3" style="display: block;">|</span></span>
```

it is almost done except this CSS problem.
i have created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bGMa9/). i want the result in single line which it is not coming.
any help will be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because they all have the style `display: block` it takes them out of the inline tekst flow and puts them on a seperate line.

Here is a fiddle that works:
http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/bGMa9/2/

If you want to style them like block elements but not make them leave tekst flow you can use `display: inline-block` or make them a block level element but use `float: left;` to make them sit next to each other.

Comment: @Pranav, do not use floats unless you know exactly what you're doing. An uncleared float can cause all sorts of layout problems. `inline-block` is a better advice in case you need to style the spans as block-level elements.

Comment: @bfavaretto: Thanks.. i 'll follow your advice.

Answer (score 2):

The spans are stacked because you gave them `display: block;`. Just remove that and they should be all inline.

**UPDATE**

You said you want to show and hide the elements. To do that with inline elements, just set `display` to `none` for hiding, and to `''` (empty string), or `inline` to show.

See http://jsfiddle.net/bGMa9/4/

Comment: actually i need to show and hide span that is why i have given block;

Comment: You can show and hide with display:inline/display:none as well. I recommend floating them like Alex Morales said to do though.